# Show that $ \lim_ {x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} =0 $ , (Try with my approach below)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ \ f : \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be a reciprocal function defined by $ \ f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$ for $ x>0 \ $

The natural logarithm is $\ln : \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R} \ $ such that
\begin{equation}
\ln(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \displaystyle\int_{[1,x]} f & \text{if} & x \geq 1, \\
-\displaystyle\int_{[x,1]} f  &  \text{if} & 0 <x<1 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

**Then show that** $ \ \ \large \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} =0 $

**Answer:**

Let us assume $ \ \epsilon>0 \ $

For $ \ x> \frac{2}{\epsilon} \ $ , let $ \ U(x,\epsilon) \ $ be the sum of the areas of the boxes $ \ [1, \frac{2}{\epsilon}] \times [0,1] \ \ and \ \ [\frac{2}{\epsilon}, x] \times [0, \frac{\epsilon}{2}] \ $

The graph is as follows:

[image]

Let $ \ U(x,\epsilon)=\text{upper sum} $ .

we can see that if we draw the graph $ \ln(x) \ $

$ U(x,\epsilon) \geq \ln (x) \ $

Now if we can show that $ \large \frac{U(x,\epsilon)}{x} < \epsilon $ , then we will have $ \large \frac{\ln (x)}{x} < \epsilon $ , which will prove that $ \ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln (x)}{x}=0 \ $

**But I am unable to show that** $ \large \frac{U(x,\epsilon)}{x} < \epsilon $ .

** Help me out and  draw the above graph clearly if possible.**

Comment: You can't use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Can Use but Have to prove with the above approach . I just need to show that $ \frac{U(x,\epsilon}{x} < \epsilon \ $ by the help of upper sum formula in the above graph

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the above approach?

Comment: The steps what I did so far in my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but a suggestion:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\log x \over x} &=& {\int_1^x {dt \over t} \over x} \\
&=& {\int_1^{x_0} {dt \over t} +\int_{x_0}^x {dt \over t} \over x } \\
&=& {1 \over x} \int_1^{x_0} {dt \over t} +\int_{x_0}^x {dt \over xt} \\
&\le& {1 \over x} \int_1^{x_0} {dt \over t} +\int_{x_0}^x {dt \over t^2} \\
&=& {1 \over x} \int_1^{x_0} {dt \over t} + {1 \over x_0} - {1 \over x} \\
&\le& {1 \over x} \int_1^{x_0} {dt \over t} + {1 \over x_0}
\end{eqnarray}

**Addendum**:

Try a partition $P=(1,x_0,x)$ to get
$\int_1^x {dt \over xt} \le {1 \over x} U(f,P) \le {1 \over x} (x_0-1+{1 \over x_0}(x-x_0)) \le {x_0-1 \over x} + {1 \over x_0}$.

Now choose $x_0$ and $x$ appropriately.

Comment: But I need to prove using those approach of $ upper \ \ sum $ which I did above

Comment: @yourmath: I added an addendum which uses an upper bound of an upper sum.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** For $x\ge1$,
$$
\frac{\log(x)}{x}=\frac1x\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}t\lt1
$$
**Hint 2:**
$$
\frac{\log(x)}x=\frac2{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\lt\frac2{\sqrt{x}}
$$

Comment: I like the second hint!

Comment: @copper.hat: this same approach gives that $\frac{\log(x)}x\lt\frac{n}{x^{\frac{n-1}n}}$

Comment: Nice. ${}{}{}{}$